# python: if - in operator. Is there a difference between these two codes?

Tags: python, in-operator

Is there a difference in these two codes?

```
if x in array[j] and array[j].index(x) == 0:
```

and,

```
if array[j] in x and x.index(array[j]) == 0:
```

How can I interpret these two codes?

For example, it would be something as

> 'r','b','rbrb'

or

> 'BRBRBBBRBRRRBBB','BRBRBRRRBRRRBRB','BBBRBBBRBRRRBBB','BRBRBRRRBRRRB',
>   'BRBRBBBRBBBRB'

The whole code looks like this:

```
array = []
for i in range(3):
    x = input()
    flag = False
    for j in range(len(array)):
        if x in array[j] and array[j].index(x) == 0:
            array[j] = x
            flag = True
            break
        if array[j] in x and x.index(array[j]) == 0:
            flag = True
            break
    if not flag:
        array.append(x)

print(array)
```

I was looking at this code for several hours to get some idea but couldn't even narrow down my questions to ask in search engines and now I getting more confused.

I was familiar with codes like...

```
if x in listA:
```

or

```
listA.index(x)
```

But having a hard time using flag = False and

```
if x in listA[j]:
```

or

```
listA[j].index(x)
```

If possible, what should I study to get more understandings to this question?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. `"foo" in "foobar"` is True; `"foobar" in "foo"` is False. `in` is not commutative.

Comment: did you write this? If not, it's worth no longer looking at it: it's a pretty bad example to be learning from.

Comment: Assume we have two cases. `'apple' in 'apple store'` and `'apple' in ['apple']`. You can start with this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is that the difference between those two codes is COMPLETELY different.

You should learn to break things down conceptually.  So you understand:

```
if x in listA:
```

but not:

```
if x in listA[j]:
```

so then what about this?:

```
listB = listA[j]
if x in listB
```

The answer is that listA is a list of things.  What those things are will vary based on your code and what you're trying to do.  In this case, the things IN listA are again lists.  The above code block demonstrates this.  You can pull the list at position 'j' out of listA and then use it just like you'd use any other list.  It doesn't matter that it happened to come from inside another list.  This is the notion of breaking things down:  **some_variable[some_index]** is one concept and **some_variable in some_list** is another.  Programming is exactly combining things in this way.

So this:

```
if x in array[j] and array[j].index(x) == 0:
```

suggests that **array[j]** is a list, and **x** is something that you might find in that list.  Similarly, since **array[j]** is a list, you can call .index() on it.  This code says nothing at all about what **x** is.  It's just something that can be put in a list.

```
if array[j] in x and x.index(array[j]) == 0:
```

this suggests that **x** is a list, and **array[j]** is something that might be in that list.  You just reverse the roles of the two things.  The important thing to realize is that **x** and **array[j]** could in general be the same object.  It's just that in the case of **x** you have a direct reference to that object, and in the case of **array[j]**, you are pulling that object out of a list.

BTW, I've been saying "list" to keep things simple.  To be more precise, whenever I've said "list" I've meant something that is a Python Sequence Type, something that has a notion of "the first item, the second item, etc."  Any number of things, including your own objects that you define, can be a Sequence type, and hence be what we're talking about above when we say "list".  With code like this, you're usually dealing with a "list", or sometimes a "tuple", which is just a "list" you can't modify.

Comment: I can't appreciate enough for your generous explanation! It did help me tremendously getting to know the differences of those two codes.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  That makes me feel really good.  I really like helping out new programmers.  Glad I could help you!

Comment: Hello Steve! How are you? If I am not interrupting nor disturbing you, may I please ask you a question regarding to Time Limit Exceeded? The only person I could think of for educational help was you. I didn't know where to send you a message other than this comment line, so here I am! Thank you for you time reading this :)

Comment: Sure!  I'd like to help you if I can.  What is your question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Hope you are having a wonderful Saturday evening. Actually I was solving on Google Code Jam yesterday and the online judgement system says I keep getting an TLE. I have changed my input() to sys.stdin.readline() and tried to make my codes really simple (I tried...) but the issue hasn't been solved yet.

Comment: Actually I made a link to google Docs. Thank you for you time! Does numerous of using of for loops may cause the TLE issue? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1T7jr4peZN3uWL5_w1zdRp1A531kuL7QJOBXywKnaTB8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I helped someone with a similar issue once.  I don't know how these online code checkers work, but in that case, the problem was that the time it took the user to input the test data was being taken into account in the total runtime.  Once I pointed this out to him, he was able to fix the problem.  Could this be the problem in your case too?

Comment: I believe that is the case. They said that the time limit applies to the sum of the compilation time and the running time. So I tried with sys.stdin.readline() to reduce some time getting inputs but I guess other things are also causing the issue. I am sorry if I'm taking your time but are there any better methods other than sys.stdin.readline() to use reducing the time getting input data?